# Syncing Data with Parse, not downloading data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, parse-platform

I have been following the How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 1 from RayWenderlinch.com I am trying to customize it to my application and have an issue with the actual downloading of the data from Parse using AFNetworking

The application should connect to parse, see the two classes "Club" and "IronSet" check and see if there are and new records (or on initial run, grab everything) and download only the newly added stuff.

Then it will save those records to core data, then delete the files from the Cache/JSONRecords/Club(or IronSet).  It seems I am never actually grabbing the data from Parse, although it is connecting successfully, and does not throw an error until it goes to delete the the files from the Cache.

I am getting the "All operations completed" indicating the SyncEngine should be complete with the download in the `downloadDataForRegisteredObjects`

**Error**

```
2013-08-26 19:39:03.981 WGT Golf Calculator[3287:c07] All operations completed
2013-08-26 19:39:03.991 WGT Golf Calculator[3287:c07] Unable to delete JSON records at Club -- file://localhost/Users/**/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/4B72F57E-264D-44F7-981D-3D921B0CC2A4/Library/Caches/JSONRecords/, reason Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x75610f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x75615e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/**/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/4B72F57E-264D-44F7-981D-3D921B0CC2A4/Library/Caches/JSONRecords/Club, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}
```

**MLVAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MLVAppDelegate.h"
#import "MLVSyncEngine.h"
#import "Club.h"
#import "IronSet.h"

@implementation MLVAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[MLVSyncEngine sharedEngine] registerNSManagedObjectClassToSync:[Club class]];
    [[MLVSyncEngine sharedEngine] registerNSManagedObjectClassToSync:[IronSet class]];

    return YES;
}
```

**MLVAFParseAPIClient.h**

```
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface MLVAFParseAPIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (MLVAFParseAPIClient *)sharedClient;

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForClass:(NSMutableString *)className parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:(NSString *)className updatedAfterDate:(NSDate *)updatedDate;

@end
```

**MLVAFParseAPIClient.m**

```
#import "MLVAFParseAPIClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString = @"https://api.parse.com/1/";
static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIApplicationId = @"APP ID REMOVED";
static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIKey = @"API KEY REMOVED";

@implementation MLVAFParseAPIClient

+ (MLVAFParseAPIClient *)sharedClient
{
    static MLVAFParseAPIClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{sharedClient = [[MLVAFParseAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:kSDFParseAPIApplicationId];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:kSDFParseAPIKey];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForClass:(NSMutableString *)className parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"classes/%@", className] parameters:parameters ];
    return request;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:(NSString *)className updatedAfterDate:(NSDate *)updatedDate
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSDictionary *parameters = nil;

    if (updatedDate) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"updatedAt\":{\"$gte\":{\"__type\":\"Date\",\"iso\":\"%@\"}}}", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];

        parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonString forKey:@"where"];
    }

    request = [self GETRequestForClass:className parameters:parameters];
    return request;
}


@end
```

**MLVCoreDataController.m**

```
#import "MLVCoreDataController.h"

@interface MLVCoreDataController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *masterManagedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundManagedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end

@implementation MLVCoreDataController

@synthesize masterManagedObjectContext = _masterManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize backgroundManagedObjectContext = _backgroundManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static MLVCoreDataController *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Used to propegate saves to the persistent store (disk) without blocking the UI
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext {
    if (_masterManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _masterManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _masterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_masterManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [_masterManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }];

    }
    return _masterManagedObjectContext;
}

// Return the NSManagedObjectContext to be used in the background during sync
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)backgroundManagedObjectContext {
    if (_backgroundManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _backgroundManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *masterContext = [self masterManagedObjectContext];
    if (masterContext != nil) {
        _backgroundManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [_backgroundManagedObjectContext setParentContext:masterContext];
        }];
    }

    return _backgroundManagedObjectContext;
}

// Return the NSManagedObjectContext to be used in the background during sync
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)newManagedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *masterContext = [self masterManagedObjectContext];
    if (masterContext != nil) {
        newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [newContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [newContext setParentContext:masterContext];
        }];
    }

    return newContext;
}

- (void)saveMasterContext {
    [self.masterManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            // do some real error handling
            NSLog(@"Could not save master context due to %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)saveBackgroundContext {
    [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            // do some real error handling
            NSLog(@"Could not save background context due to %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WGTCalculator" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"WGTCalcul.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}


@end
```

**MLVSyncEngine.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {
    MLVObjectSynced = 0,
    MLVObjectCreated,
    MLVObjectDeleted,
} MLVObjectSyncStatus;

@interface MLVSyncEngine : NSObject
@property (atomic, readonly) BOOL syncInProgress;


+ (MLVSyncEngine *)sharedEngine;

- (void)registerNSManagedObjectClassToSync:(Class)aClass;
- (void)startSync;

@end
```

**MLVSyncEngine.m**

```
#import "MLVSyncEngine.h"

#import "MLVCoreDataController.h"
#import "MLVAFParseAPIClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

NSString * const kMLVSyncEngineInitialCompleteKey = @"MLVSyncEngineInitialSyncCompleted";
NSString * const kMLVSyncEngineSyncCompletedNotificationName = @"MLVSyncEngineSyncCompleted";

@interface MLVSyncEngine ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *registeredClassesToSync;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

@end

@implementation MLVSyncEngine

@synthesize registeredClassesToSync = _registeredClassesToSync;
@synthesize syncInProgress = _syncInProgress;
@synthesize dateFormatter = _dateFormatter;


+ (MLVSyncEngine *)sharedEngine
{
    static MLVSyncEngine *sharedEngine = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedEngine = [[MLVSyncEngine alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedEngine;
}

- (void)registerNSManagedObjectClassToSync:(Class)aClass
{
    if (!self.registeredClassesToSync) {
        self.registeredClassesToSync = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    if ([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]) {
        if (![self.registeredClassesToSync containsObject:NSStringFromClass(aClass)]) {
            [self.registeredClassesToSync addObject:NSStringFromClass(aClass)];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to register %@ as it is already registered", NSStringFromClass(aClass));
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to reguster %@ as it is not a subclass of NSManagedObject", NSStringFromClass(aClass));
    }
}

- (BOOL)initialSyncComplete{
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kMLVSyncEngineInitialCompleteKey] boolValue];
}

- (void)setInitialSyncCompleted{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kMLVSyncEngineInitialCompleteKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)executeSyncCompletedOperations {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setInitialSyncCompleted];

        NSError *error = nil;
        [[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving background context after creating objects on server: %@", error);
        }

        [[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:kMLVSyncEngineSyncCompletedNotificationName
         object:nil];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"syncInProgress"];
        _syncInProgress = NO;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"syncInProgress"];
    });
}

- (void)startSync
{
    if (!self.syncInProgress) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"syncInProgress"];
        _syncInProgress = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"syncInProgress"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{[self downloadDataForRegisteredObjects:YES];
        });
    }
}


- (NSDate *)mostRecentUpdatedAtDateForEntityWithName:(NSString *)entityName {
    __block NSDate *date = nil;
    //
    // Create a new fetch request for the specified entity
    //
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    //
    // Set the sort descriptors on the request to sort by updatedAt in descending order
    //
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"updatedAt" ascending:NO]]];
    //
    // You are only interested in 1 result so limit the request to 1
    //
    [request setFetchLimit:1];
    [[[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *results = [[[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if ([results lastObject])   {
            //
            // Set date to the fetched result
            //
            date = [[results lastObject] valueForKey:@"updatedAt"];
        }
    }];

    return date;
}

- (void)newManagedObjectWithClassName:(NSString *)className forRecord:(NSDictionary *)record {
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:[[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];
    [record enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [self setValue:obj forKey:key forManagedObject:newManagedObject];
    }];
    [record setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MLVObjectSynced] forKey:@"syncStatus"];
}

- (void)updateManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject withRecord:(NSDictionary *)record {
    [record enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [self setValue:obj forKey:key forManagedObject:managedObject];
    }];
}


- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key forManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"createdAt"] || [key isEqualToString:@"updatedAt"]) {
        NSDate *date = [self dateUsingStringFromAPI:value];
        [managedObject setValue:date forKey:key];
    } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        if ([value objectForKey:@"__type"]) {
            NSString *dataType = [value objectForKey:@"__type"];
            if ([dataType isEqualToString:@"Date"]) {
                NSString *dateString = [value objectForKey:@"iso"];
                NSDate *date = [self dateUsingStringFromAPI:dateString];
                [managedObject setValue:date forKey:key];
            } else if ([dataType isEqualToString:@"File"]) {
                NSString *urlString = [value objectForKey:@"url"];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSData *dataResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                [managedObject setValue:dataResponse forKey:key];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unknown Data Type Received");
                [managedObject setValue:nil forKey:key];
            }
        }
    } else {
        [managedObject setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)managedObjectsForClass:(NSString *)className withSyncStatus:(MLVObjectSyncStatus)syncStatus {
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:className];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"syncStatus = %d", syncStatus];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];

    return results;
}

- (NSArray *)managedObjectsForClass:(NSString *)className sortedByKey:(NSString *)key usingArrayOfIds:(NSArray *)idArray inArrayOfIds:(BOOL)inIds {
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:className];
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    if (inIds) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId IN %@", idArray];
    } else {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (objectId IN %@)", idArray];
    }

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectId" ascending:YES]]];
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];

    return results;
}


- (void)downloadDataForRegisteredObjects:(BOOL)useUpdatedAtDate {
    NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *className in self.registeredClassesToSync) {
        NSDate *mostRecentUpdatedDate = nil;
        if (useUpdatedAtDate) {
            mostRecentUpdatedDate = [self mostRecentUpdatedAtDateForEntityWithName:className];
        }
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[MLVAFParseAPIClient sharedClient]
                                        GETRequestForAllRecordsOfClass:className
                                        updatedAfterDate:mostRecentUpdatedDate];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[MLVAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];
                NSLog(@"Response for %@: %@", className, responseObject);

            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request for class %@ failed with error: %@", className, error);
        }];

        [operations addObject:operation];
    }

    [[MLVAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"All operations completed");

[self processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData];
    }];
}

- (void)processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[MLVCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    //
    // Iterate over all registered classes to sync
    //
    for (NSString *className in self.registeredClassesToSync) {
        if (![self initialSyncComplete]) {
            NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [self JSONDictionaryForClassWithName:className];
            NSArray *records = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
            for (NSDictionary *record in records) {
                [self newManagedObjectWithClassName:className forRecord:record];
            }
        } else {

            NSArray *downloadedRecords = [self JSONDataRecordsForClass:className sortedByKey:@"objectId"];
            if ([downloadedRecords lastObject]) {

                NSArray *storedRecords = [self managedObjectsForClass:className sortedByKey:@"objectId" usingArrayOfIds:[downloadedRecords valueForKey:@"objectId"] inArrayOfIds:YES];
                int currentIndex = 0;

                for (NSDictionary *record in downloadedRecords) {
                    NSManagedObject *storedManagedObject = nil;

                    if ([storedRecords count] > currentIndex) {
                        storedManagedObject = [storedRecords objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
                    }

                    if ([[storedManagedObject valueForKey:@"objectId"] isEqualToString:[record valueForKey:@"objectId"]]) {

                        [self updateManagedObject:[storedRecords objectAtIndex:currentIndex] withRecord:record];
                    } else {

                        [self newManagedObjectWithClassName:className forRecord:record];
                    }
                    currentIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to save context for class %@", className);
            }
        }];


        [self deleteJSONDataRecordsForClassWithName:className];
        [self executeSyncCompletedOperations];
    }
}



- (void)initializeDateFormatter {
    if (!self.dateFormatter) {
        self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
        [self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    }
}

- (NSDate *)dateUsingStringFromAPI:(NSString *)dateString {
    [self initializeDateFormatter];
    dateString = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length]-5)];

    return [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}

- (NSString *)dateStringForAPIUsingDate:(NSDate *)date {
    [self initializeDateFormatter];
    NSString *dateString = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    dateString = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length]-1)];
    dateString = [dateString stringByAppendingFormat:@".000Z"];

    return dateString;
}

#pragma mark - File Management

- (NSURL *)applicationCacheDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSURL *)JSONDataRecordsDirectory{

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"JSONRecords/" relativeToURL:[self applicationCacheDirectory]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[url path] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
    return url;
}



-(void)writeJSONResponse:(id)response toDiskForClassWithName:(NSString *)className{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:className relativeToURL:[self JSONDataRecordsDirectory]] ;
    if (![(NSDictionary *)response writeToFile:[fileURL path] atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving response to disk, will attempt to remove NSNull values and try again.");
        //remove NSNulls and try again...
        NSArray *records = [response objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSMutableArray *nullFreeRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *record in records) {
            NSMutableDictionary *nullFreeRecord = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:record];
            [record enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                    [nullFreeRecord setValue:nil forKey:key];
                }
            }];
            [nullFreeRecords addObject:nullFreeRecord];
        }

        NSDictionary *nullFreeDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:nullFreeRecords forKey:@"results"];

        if (![nullFreeDictionary writeToFile:[fileURL path] atomically:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"Failed all attempts to save response to disk: %@", response);
        }
    }
}

- (void)deleteJSONDataRecordsForClassWithName:(NSString *)className {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:className relativeToURL:[self JSONDataRecordsDirectory]];

                  NSError *error = nil;
                  BOOL deleted = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];
                  if (!deleted) {
                      NSLog(@"Unable to delete JSON records at %@, reason %@", url, error);
                  }

}

- (NSDictionary *)JSONDictionaryForClassWithName:(NSString *)className {
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:className relativeToURL:[self JSONDataRecordsDirectory]];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
}

- (NSArray *)JSONDataRecordsForClass:(NSString *)className sortedByKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [self JSONDictionaryForClassWithName:className];
    NSArray *records = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
    return [records sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:YES]]];
}
@end
```

Comment: I have removed the MLVDataController.h and the CoreData Model files, as it was over the char limit.  I know paste sites are in bad form, but they look like http://codetidy.com/6540/

Comment: Just curious, why not just use the iOS framework, and issue queries for PFObjects ?

Comment: Are you seeing the NSLog() results from the parse.com HTTP responses, before you execute the saveJSONtoDisk method? What happens if you set a breakpoint in the saveJSONResponse method? Why else would the directories not be present, unless they were never created?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if your data model is that simple, and you're deleting the local persistent store / cache on every load, you probably would be much better off *not* using Core Data.

Keep it simple by loading data as needed. Save a cache using `NSCoding`, to be loaded initially as a placeholder, while the app waits for new information to be downloaded.

Comment: This is just the starting point of the data model. Once the user has selected items from Core Data, then they will be cached.  And using Parse was to be able to load new items as needed. 

PS. I just googled NSCoding, saw your name and realized I just listened to your podcast on Helios.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the answer was pretty straight forward, the tutorial uses an older Version of AFNetworking where AFHTTPRequestOperation can download the data but does not see it as JSON.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[MLVAFParseAPIClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];
                NSLog(@"Response for %@: %@", className, responseObject);
            }
        }
```

Needed to be updated with AFJSONRequestOperation

```
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request
                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
         {
             NSDictionary * responseObject = (NSDictionary * )JSON;
             if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                 NSLog(@"Response for %@: %@", className, responseObject);
                 [self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];
```